# Why does [HttpPost] only pick up 'EditorFor'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC Razor and when I try to edit something, I pass it through a `ViewModel` it contains all of the necessary information, I have tested this.

Here is my View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollectionId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CollectionId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BrandName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BrandName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Season)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Season)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Season)
    </div>
```

As you can see, I am only using `@Html.EditorFor` on the information that they can change as this is all I want to change. But I feel its necessary to show them the other information just so they know exactly what they are editing.

My question is, how I can I achieve the equivalent of an `@Html.EditorFor` passing back the information, without actually allowing them to edit it?

Comment: If the information isn't being edited, why do you even need to pass it to your controller when the form is submitted? Presumably you aren't allowing it to be edited for a good reason - if you allowed it to post back the data, what is to stop a malicious user from editing data they wouldn't normally be allowed to edit?

Comment: Bit hard to identify the `Collection` they would like to edit with only the one field of information would it not?

Comment: it's a very important point. even if you don't allow to edit the data, a "bad user" could pass his own changed data anyway. you could achieve this by checking the data against your existing data or just update the needed object values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use Html.HiddenFor to pass their values back to the controller.

e.g.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CollectionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CollectionId)
</div>
```

Comment: Would this still display the data though?

Comment: if you still use DisplayFor: yes